# When using mingw64, should the file path use A or B

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

I use mingw64 to write c programs on Windows 10. I heard that the c compiler is ported from Linux to Windows, and the separators used in the file path of Windows and Linux are different, so should I use "/" or "\" when writing programs?

Answer (score 1):

Always use `/`. The Windows API understands `C:/` as well as `C:\` while for Posix systems `\` is a character like any other, so **one** directory can be actually be named `foo\bar` in such systems. Programs aiming for portability  use `/` as a directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Ted Lyngmo's answer, `\` sometimes used to escape the next character, example: before my edit, your question did not show the `\` character, the second " in "\" was shown as " instead of \".

So, use `/` to avoid confusion.

Example of a mistake that happens due to `\`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("\");
}
```

will cause an error in usual compilers saying `missing terminating " character`.

And paths such as `C:\example\abc\x20` will become gibberish text and one thing that I am sure is that `\x20` will become a space, and pass the compiler error detection.